# Radioactivity inside black hole

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon, radioactivity

This is thought experiment. I know we can not insert or watch happening inside black hole. But for sake of thought experiment let's think this is possible.

Suppose we have 1 kg of material X with half life period of 1 day for example.
And now suppose we have capability to insert this material X into black hole and see what's happening inside.

So if this X of 1 kg is put inside black hole and then we observed after 1 day. So it's quantity then would be reduced to half of its original?

How would Relativity affects Radioactivity inside black hole?

Comment: You cannot observe what goes on inside a black hole because nothing can escape it.

Answer (score -1):

1. radioactive decay conserves energy. so the total contained energy in the black hole is the same. energy and mass are interchangeable.
2. Weak decays depend on the environment. E.g. free neutrons decay, but are stable in neutron stars. If gravity is even stronger, nothing could be released from the nucleus, so radioactive decay doesn't occur. Everything is compressed into the singularity or whatever exists at this point